# Learning about diffraction of waves

Tags: optics, waves, resource-recommendations, diffraction

I'm a math major learning some physics for a QM class. I am looking for some sources to learn about diffraction of waves.

Online, I've found some treatments on YouTube and other sites, but these seem to be vague in (i) the kind of wave they are talking about (transverse or longitudinal), and (ii) give a more intuitive understanding, then state the formula, rather than delving deeper into it.

Therefore, I'm looking for a **source that models wave diffraction (through a single-slit, at least) in the transverse and longitudinal wave case + does so in a mathematically rigorous way**. I'm specifically doing this to understand how waves would behave in the double-split experiment, if that matters.

It's been a while since I've done physics, so I'm honestly not sure if, for example, the Huygens' principle is relevant for light waves (it seems to be for sound waves specifically, but I may be wrong here). Therefore, I wanted an authoritative answer!

Comment: Just read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction_equation It doesn't matter what the aperture is: one slit, two slit, $n$ slits...it's just diffraction. Ofc, with multiple slits, the Fourier transform of the aperture looks like and interference pattern.

Comment: @JEB Is this what is taught at an undergraduate level? seems more complicated than what i've come across. thank you though